# file read, write and save

Tags: java, file, jms

I use java to read a file from a path and want to send it via jms. that works so far, but I need to save it to a different path (to a directory, not as file, cause there are multiple files to load and save.) I kinda know I can just save the message. But I have no idea how that works.

```
Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archive));
```

That's the snipplet that I tried. but I can't write to the archive (access denied) even though I have complete access to everything.
Thanks for any help!
EDIT!!

```
for (File x1 : files){
                i++;
                x1.toString();
                String t ;
                FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream(x1+"2");
```

works now with getName, but if i have test.xml it returns test.xml2 how can i fix that?

Comment: You might have access, but that doesn't mean that the program on the end of your JMS message (might be the same program?) does.

Comment: Not sure I understood, what is archive? Also not sure I understood your problem

Comment: If you want to write a file into a certain directory you still need to use a file name after the directory name. If `archive` refers to a directory, you need to add a separator and some file name. If you have multiple files, add numbers to a file name, e.g. `"text" + i + ".dat"`. - If this isn't your problem, fix your Q, please.

Comment: the problem is, i read the files one by one, i _could_ use a for (i=0)etc but it would always start at 0 (since it runs again for each file with i=0. also i dont know how i can make the title variable so file a would be file a+ 1 and file b would be file b+1 ...(does that make any sense?)

Comment: it should kinda work like camel. from (somewhere).to(archive?noop=true).to(queue) but in java :D

Answer (score 0):

that's how it works!

```
for (File x1 : files){
                i++;
                String x2=x1.getName().replaceAll(".xml", "").toString();
                FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream(archive+x2+"2"+".xml");
```

fyi archive is just the filepath where it schould be archived ;D